# HLookup - Run-time error 424 - Object required

Tags: excel, object

i'm basic at VBasic. Would like some help in an error (damn, appeared suddenly without changing nothing). Found some questions similar to mine, but couldn't resolve the problem. Here's the error line.

```
Camposcomplementares.Portar1.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.HLookup(Sheets("Admin_Lists").Range("BH45"), Sheets("Admin_Lists").Range("BB11:BG38"), 14, False)
```

After that : Camposcomplementares.Show -> opens the userform (if it wasn't the error)

Camposcomplementares = userform
Portar1 = is a textbox's name in the userform (double checked for errors in name)
Range("BH45") is an integer number - checked and it's ok
Range("BB11:BG38") = is the table with the values
Notes : - checked the similar formula in excel and it works ok.
        - dont use "explicit" and no variable defined

Hope is enough for someone to help me.It worked before :( . Tkx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to start with something really small. Like this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
       Debug.Print .HLookup(Sheets("A_L").Range("A1"), Sheets("A_L").Range("B1:C100"), 2,0)
    End With
End Sub
```

and to make it work.

Then slowly exchange the `Range("A1")` with `Range("BH45")` and `Range("B1:C100")` with `Range("B1:C100")`. Does it work? Is it because `Range(BH45)` has a `!Div/0` error or sheet `"A_L"` does not exist?

Probably it works so far. You may continue debugging, writing something like this:

```
Public Sub TestMe2()
    Camposcomplementares.Portar1.Text = "Something"
End Sub
```

Does it work? How do you refer to the UserForm? Where is the text located? In the userform or in a module?

Comment: Hi, tkx for your fast answer.  Double checked and "deleted" that HLookup line. And found that the problem is with "Camposcomplementares.show". I'm calling it from a module which is run when i press a button. The userform "Camposcomplementares" is a userform in the "Forms" directory. Basically i want to get value of a cell in Excel and put it in the "Portar1" textbox in "Camposcomplementares" userform. Hope i was clear.

Comment: Solved!!! Such a stupid error!!! In the form's Initialize, it was "Private Sub Userform_Initialize()" instead of "Private Sub Camposcomplementares_Initialize()".  Changed it and it worked! The stupid thing was that that name was there way long time before (when i created the initialize i've seen that, but as it worked, i didn't bothered). @Vityata : tkx anyway for your time!